# Remove random background from video using ffmpeg or Python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, ffmpeg, computer-vision

I want to remove background from a person's video using `ffmpeg` or `Python`. If I record a video at any place, detect the person in the video and then remove anything except that person. Not asking for green or single color background as that can be done through chromakey and I am not looking for that.

I've tried this (https://tryolabs.com/blog/2018/04/17/announcing-luminoth-0-1/) approach but it is giving me output of rectangular box. It is informative enough as area to explore is narrow down enough but still need to remove total background.
I've also tried `grabcut` (https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) but that need user interaction otherwise result isn't too good.
I've also tried to use `ffmpeg` and found this example (http://oioiiooixiii.blogspot.com/2016/09/ffmpeg-extract-foreground-moving.html) but it needs still image so I tried to take background picture before recording video with a person but there are many things required to take difference between background image and video frame.

For `opencv` approach, I've tried this.

```
img = cv.imread('pic.png')
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
rect = (39, 355, 1977, 2638)
cv.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img), plt.colorbar(), plt.show()
```

But it is removing some of person's part too.
Also tried `ffmpeg` way but not a good result.

```
ffmpeg -report -y -i "img.jpg" -i "vid.mov" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=yuva444p,lut=c3=128[video2withAlpha],[0:v][video2withAlpha]blend=all_mode=difference[out]" -map "[out]" "output.mp4"
```

All I need is just a person's image/video take under any normal background without user interaction like area selection or any other thing like that. `Luminoth` has trained data but that is giving box of person not exact person so that I can remove. Any help or guidance to remove background will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a deep learning based approach. Here is an example repo:

```
https://github.com/TianzhongSong/Person-Segmentation-Keras
```

This will give you a mask for a person on arbitrary background. Just load the images with opencv and put them through the network.

Comment: Excellent. I think this can give me what I'm looking for.

Comment: Surely will do that as soon as I get my correct result from this. Mentioned dataset is giving 404 right now. So trying to find that dataset from somewhere so that I can test that.

Comment: I can't download dataset because it's on `baidu` and need to create account on it which I can't because I'm not China based.